# /bb|[^b]{2}/ how does it work?

Tags: regex

Can someone please explain? I read this on a [t-shirt](http://www.thinkgeek.com/tshirts-apparel/unisex/itdepartment/57f0/):

[image]

It seems to be saying: "To be or not to be"

How? I do not seem to be finding 'e'? :p

How exactly does this regex techy/geeky?

Comment: its either two b's, or not two b's.

Comment: It's not spelling it exactly; the letter "B" and "Be" are pronouced the same. Nerd jokes aren't an exact science.

Comment: C'mon guys, there are *really* stupid questions being asked here that receive less down-votes.

Comment: How can understanding working of a regex be marked as "off topic" :)

Comment: No one wants to answer? Okay, cool.

Comment: People have right to down-vote. I have some 300+ score, make it 0. I do not mind. I just want to understand why? Can I not ask how a regex works? Is this question that bad? How I have put this question in any other way? How? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming #  for comments:

```
 /
  bb     # two b's
  |      #  or 
  [^     #  not
   b]{2} #  two b's
 /
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I am one step closer to being geek :D

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately the correct description would be: "two b or not b and not b" or "two b and two not-b" (which doesn't really gets close to "to be or not to be").

```
/bb|[^b]{2}/ => /bb|[^b][^b]/
```

Of course "two b or not two b" matches anything when expressed in regular expression!

Comment: To be exact, it matches any *even* number of characters. Plus, the description would be more like *"Two **b** or **not b**, two times."*

Comment: @Tomalak It depends how you translate not two b. I'd think it is something like `/(?!bb).*/` and that would match anything except `"bb"`.

Comment: Well, regex are red from left to right. And knowing nothing else, `[^b]` is *"not b"*. The quantifier comes after that. *"not b and not b"* would be `[^b][^b]`. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak And that's exactly what I wrote in my answer ;-) Nevertheless it doesn't match the original phrase either.

Comment: Exactly! To expand, the string `ab` *is* **not 2 b's**, but the regex doesn't match that. It should be `/bb|(?!bb)../`, or `/bb|[^b].|.[^b]/`, which as you said, matches everything (with at lease 2 characters). To beat a dead horse, the regex is on the general form `aV~a`, which is a tautology - it will always be true. Conclusion - t-shirts make poor regex tutorials.

Comment: /bb|[^2]{b} - sounds more like "to (two) be or not to (two) be?? :D

Answer (score 0):

Read it out aloud: "BB, or not B, not B". Or, "Two B, or not two B". Hmm... not sure, somebody wants to check for the letter B I guess.